# Grub - Windows Invalid EFI file path

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, uefi

I have 2 hdd, Windows on the first, I installed Mint on the second.

This destroyed the bootloader so I used boot-repair to restore it.
Boot-repair identified both OS.

Now my fresh Mint install boots fine but my Windows tells me

> Invalid EFI file path

Here is my [boot-repair info](http://paste2.org/JDNyINeI)

Can someone help me to restore my Windows boot ?